# One div extends into another div

Tags: html, css

I've made an image of the situation which I hope makes things a bit easier to understand.

[image]

As you can see there are two divs within a div. When I resize the screen the text that's inside the right div goes into the logo (the left div). What I want is that the text (and the righter div) won't go into the logo. Both divs are floated, each to their corresponding side. Do you have some suggestions for me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A jsFiddle would help even more.

Comment: @user2441823 Please post your relevant code here or fiddle it using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Set a `min-width` on the container.

Comment: Show us your code. This doesn't happen if the two inner red blocks are floats inside the outer red block as their common parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me like a `float` issue. Ensure that you clear the base of a div that contains floated elements.

```
<div>
   <p>floated left element</p>
   <p> also floated left element</p>
   <p> some text </p>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you're right about clear:both, hard to determine without code but that's pretty common.

Comment: Jep that seems to do the trick